# C# 9 new "nested switch expression" with relational patterns

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

In https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/#relational-patterns there's an example of using "nested switch expression":

```
DeliveryTruck t when t.GrossWeightClass switch
{
    > 5000 => 10.00m + 5.00m,
    < 3000 => 10.00m - 2.00m,
    _ => 10.00m,
},
```

instead of:

```
    DeliveryTruck t when t.GrossWeightClass > 5000 => 10.00m + 5.00m,
    DeliveryTruck t when t.GrossWeightClass < 3000 => 10.00m - 2.00m,
    DeliveryTruck _ => 10.00m,
```

But I can't get it to work... My full code:

```
public class DeliveryTruck {
    public int GrossWeightClass { get; set; }
}

public class Class1 {
    public decimal CalculateTollOriginal(object vehicle) =>
        vehicle switch
        {
            DeliveryTruck t when (t.GrossWeightClass > 5000) => 10.00m + 5.00m,
            DeliveryTruck t when (t.GrossWeightClass < 3000) => 10.00m - 2.00m,
            DeliveryTruck t => 10.00m,

            { } => throw new System.ArgumentException(message: "Not a known vehicle type", paramName: nameof(vehicle)),
            null => throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(vehicle))
        };

    public decimal CalculateTollNestedSwitch(object vehicle) =>
        vehicle switch
        {
            DeliveryTruck t when t.GrossWeightClass switch
            {
                > 5000 => 10.00m + 5.00m,
                < 3000 => 10.00m - 2.00m,
                _ => 10.00m,
            },

            { } => throw new System.ArgumentException(message: "Not a known vehicle type", paramName: nameof(vehicle)),
            null => throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(vehicle))
        };

}
```

And I'm getting compilation errors with dotnet 5.0.100:

```
C:\Users\pkruk\source\repos\CSharp9\PatternMatching2_NestedSwitch.cs(29,14): error CS1003: Syntax error, '=>' expected [C:\Users\pkruk\source\repos\CSharp9\CSharp9.csproj]
C:\Users\pkruk\source\repos\CSharp9\PatternMatching2_NestedSwitch.cs(29,14): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ',' [C:\Users\pkruk\source\repos\CSharp9\CSharp9.csproj]
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Asked on the [dotnet/csharplang Gitter](https://gitter.im/dotnet/csharplang?at=5fb7a1202a6c794bd8f79071). The code in Mads' post doesn't look familiar from following the design of relational patterns... It works if you replace the `when` with `=>`, but that's not quite the same e.g. if you want to remove the `_` case and fall through to the error case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would need is

```
public decimal CalculateTollNestedSwitch(object vehicle) => vehicle switch
{
    DeliveryTruck t => t.GrossWeightClass switch
    {
        > 5000 => 10.00m + 5.00m,
        < 3000 => 10.00m - 2.00m,
        _ => 10.00m,
    },

    { } => throw new System.ArgumentException(message: "Not a known vehicle type", paramName: nameof(vehicle)),
    null => throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(vehicle))
};
```